# Is there a way to define a function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters in Python?

Tags: python

I am curious about whether it is possible to define a function that can take any number of parameters in Python. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*args` or `**kwargs`

See [this article](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Multiple_Function_Arguments) for more in depth information about that.

---

**EDIT**

@Dash also mentioned [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/8286364) great answer from Peter Hoffmann on this subject

Comment: I would also mention this question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters